# Using a fragment as a Thymeleaf variable to th:with and a th:data-content attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm looking to do something like the following.  Is this possible or is there a workaround?

**myFragment.html**

```
<div th:fragment="myContent(someObject)">
  Some popover strings with some business logic
  <span th:text="${someObject.property}">[object property]</span>
</div>
```

**myTemplate.html**

```
<!-- how would I correct this so that the fragment is evaluated? -->
<div th:with="popoverContent = ${myFragment :: myContent(someObject)}">    
    <a th:data-content="${popoverContent}"></a>
</div>
```

Can I insert a fragment within a `th:with` as a variable?  I can create `popoverContent` server-side, but I'm thinking there's likely a better way.

**Update: More Specifics on Use Case**

I need tooltips with some basic math formulas to be styled.

In `myFragment.html`, I have an HTML `table` with multiple `th:cases` in a `th:switch`.  Each `td` has a tooltip with the calculated values.

The tooltip reads something like, "Here is how we calculate your custom ratio: ((1 + 5) / 3) + 1 = 3", so we'd style it to be read more clearly.

It would be messy to do it server-side, and the best alternative right now is that I avoid using a `th:fragment` and supply the logic in each `th:data-content` field directly in each `th:case`.

It seems like a small thing, but it's surprisingly been somewhat of a headache since the calculations can sometimes change, and so modifying multiple places is error-prone and a chore.  And we do this same sort of thing overall in multiple places.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `<div th:with="popoverContent=~{myFragment :: myContent}"> <p th:insert="${popoverContent}">`. You'd normally use a message source and message resolver for externalizing strings. Check [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text)

Comment: Ok, TBH it's a little more than strings (there's some logic too).  I'm getting null for the `popoverContent` when I try to use this route - let me take a closer look.

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear.  The fragment contains logic.  Changing the first `$` in `myTemplate.html` to a tilda works to insert `myFragment`, but the logic is not evaluated (processed).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what is not evaluated. Can you provide an example of the logic which you like to be evaluated?

Comment: In the above example, it would be `<span th:text="${someObject.property}">[object property]</span>`  It seems that `someObject` is evaluated as an empty string (not actually null).  But I'm able to print out property values for it on `myTemplate.html`.

Comment: I have the same requirement. I opened https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/697 to hopefully get support for this in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to get a fragment as text, but here is one way you could do it with jquery:

```
<!-- onload -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dest').attr('data-content', $('#source').html());
    });
</script>
```

And the html would look something like:

```
<div id="dest"></div>
<div id="source" style="display: none;" th:insert="~{popover :: popover}" />
```

After doing rendering and inspecting the html in Chrome's developer tools I can see:

```
<div id="dest" data-content="<div>Hello, I am a popover</div>"></div>
<div id="source" style="display: none;"><div>Hello, I am a popover</div></div>
```

Comment: Would have to make some edits since I would have multiple `id="dest"` appearances, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add template using `~{}`  instead of `${}` as specified in the first comment. The reason your someObject is not evaluated IMO is you are not using variable type  expression i.e. `${someObject}`

Overall you should do something like below:

**myFragment.html**

```
<div th:fragment="myContent(someObject)">
    Some popover strings with some business logic
    <span th:text="${someObject.property}">[object property]</span>
</div>
```

**myTemplate.html**

```
<div th:with="popoverContent = ~{myFragment :: myContent(${someObject})}">
    <th:block th:insert="${popoverContent}"></th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: it evaluates with `th:insert="${popoverContent}"`, but not with `th:data-content="${popoverContent}"`.  I think the issue is because `th:insert` will actually process the fragment, and this `th:data-content` is implementing like `th:text` and NOT processing.  Here's the background: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451 under the section "Writing fragments as text, not as... fragments"

Comment: +1. so close... maybe there's a clever way to get the same thing done.  Really, now I would just need to store the result of `th:insert` in a variable for `th:data-content` to display.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: It's the same use case.  I need tooltips with some basic math formulas to be styled.  It's in a table and each td has a tooltip with the calculated values.  Like, "Here is how we calculate your custom ratio: (1 + 5) / 3 = 2".  Feels a bit silly to do it server-side.

Comment: Updated the question with my use case

Comment: Sorry was on the mobile and somehow missed your comment. Couldn't you just take the text value of the div from java script if you wanted the processed text as a value. For example setting a hidden div via thymeleaf and setting the data-content attribute to that value on load of the page.

Comment: Can you post an example?