# Thymeleaf: How to load a thymeleaf processed fragment in a local variable using th:with?

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<div th:with="local_var = ~{fragment_file :: fragment_name}"></div>
```

The above code get's me the html markup from the fragment but fail's to evaluate the thymeleaf data in it (for e.g. ${data} used in the fragment is returned without evaluating it)

```
<div th:replace="fragment_file :: fragment_name"></div>
```

On the other hand, if I use th:replace like above for the same fragment, it processes the fragment just fine:

**Is there a way to call a fragment and load the evaluated fragment in a th:with variable ?**

Comment: one of the answers to this offers the same sort of question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774902/using-a-fragment-as-a-thymeleaf-variable-to-thwith-and-a-thdata-content-attrib

Comment: Thanks @bphilipnyc. I think the jQuery solution accepted there only works as a th:replace would work but in my case I wanted to store the fragment in a th:with local variable and pass it as a parameter to other fragments

Comment: what about the other answer to the question?  same issue?

Comment: yes, it works with th:replace or th:insert but not with th:with